# Como colocar valores de array dentro de uma variável?

Tags: php, array, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis

Ola, sou novo em programação e estou fazendo uma chamada de um array de objetos assim:

```php
$retorno = enviarREST($url, $data);
$content = json_decode($retorno);

foreach ($content->retorno as $produto){
    echo "SKU: ".$produto->codigo . "<br/>";  
    echo "NCM:  ".$produto->ncm . "<br/>";
    echo "Origem:  ".$produto->origem . "<br/>";
    echo "EAN:  ".$produto->gtin . "<br/>";
    echo "Codigo fabricante:  ".$produto->codigo_pelo_fornecedor . "<br/>";
}
```

e meu objetivo é colocar o resultado dessa chama dentro de uma varialvel, existe alguma ferramenta pra isso?

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi, mas não seria só criar uma variável antes e concatena-la?

```php
$res = "";   
foreach ($content->retorno as $produto) {
    $res = "SKU: ".$produto->codigo . "<br/>";  
    $res .= "NCM:  ".$produto->ncm . "<br/>";
    $res .= "Origem:  ".$produto->origem . "<br/>";
    $res .= "EAN:  ".$produto->gtin . "<br/>";
    $res .= "Codigo fabricante:  ".$produto->codigo_pelo_fornecedor . "<br/>";
}
    
echo($res);
```